# How to filter out what gets returned to client when invoking api gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have api gateway integration with step function.  When I invoke it I get in a response more than I want to return to client. How do I filter out what gets returned to client? I only want values in "output" field. Currently, I get following

```
{
  "billingDetails": {
    "billedDurationInMilliseconds": 200,
    "billedMemoryUsedInMB": 64
  },
  "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:0935357777988:express:mystatemachine-stag:d12cb1cd-2094-4690-91f6-31af336e1d0f:42fd1794-c810-46d2-a60d-bb68ed5ad31c",
  "input": "{\"pzId\":\"01GQTJW20W5J99R0ZXD1T3W0Q6\"}",
  "inputDetails": {
    "__type": "com.amazonaws.swf.base.model#CloudWatchEventsExecutionDataDetails",
    "included": true
  },
  "name": "d12cb1cd-2094-4690-91f6-31af336e1d0f",
  "output": "{\"details\":{},
  "outputDetails": {
    "__type": "com.amazonaws.swf.base.model#CloudWatchEventsExecutionDataDetails",
    "included": true
  },
  "startDate": 1.686226844882E9,
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:0935357777988:mystateMachine-stag",
  "status": "SUCCEEDED",
  "stopDate": 1.686226845062E9
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant bits of your state machine definition.  Also, the JSON around `"output"` appears to be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [API Gateway HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html), you cannot (to the best of my current knowledge) manipulate the response from the [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) API. You can with [API Gateway REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html).

With REST APIs, you can use a Mapping Template in your response configuration to return. For example, you can use the [$input.path function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference) to provide a JSON Path expression that will grab the `output` key.

```
$input.path('$.output')
```

You can also check out [this documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-step-functions-rest-api-integration-cdk.html) that describes how to use the [StepFunctionsRestApi CDK construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.StepFunctionsRestApi.html) to simplify setting this integration up.

Comment: And I assume one cannot modify output from step function either to return only "output" ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What you see here is the response from the Step Functions API Action. These APIs have a strongly defined structure and one can't omit portions optionally.